# Create custom array of input name values

Tags: php, laravel, forms, backend

If I have two inputs like the following

```
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="text" name="name">
```

Then it is possible to get values in array on backend like this
array("id"=>"name")

If it is possible then how it can be done?

Comment: Try and submit the form. See what you get when you do print_r($_POST);

Comment: May I know why do you need such thing `array("id"=>"name")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are doing well and good.

Umm, I just got your query. You want to make id as a key and name as a value in array. So here, May be i found your solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="id[]">
        <input type="text" name="name[]">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $combineArr = array_combine($_POST['id'], $_POST['name']);
        print_r($combineArr);
    }
?>
```

From the above code you can get answer like below,

```
Array ( [id] => name )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send your post via POST method.

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" 
           value="Send"/>
</form>
```

After that :

```
<?php
$array = [$_POST['id'] => $_POST['name']];
```